# Fraction part of the decimal number not included to multiplication in php

Tags: numbers, multiplication

I have multiplication code for an API.

```
foreach($cXML->results->row as $sale)
        {
            $subId      = $sale->subid;
            $status     = $sale->status;
            $transId    = "ad".$sale->OrderID;
            $amount     = $sale->total_commission;
            $createdDate= $sale->date;
            $subIdExplode = explode('-', $subId);
            $userId     = $subIdExplode[0];
            $retailerId = $subIdExplode[1];
            $retailerQuery = mysql_query("select * from db_retailers where retailer_id = '".$retailerId."'");
            $retailer = mysql_fetch_array($retailerQuery);

            if(trim($retailer['member_top']) != "")
            {
                $commision = $retailer['coef']*$amount;
            }
        }
```

Input example;

- $retailer['coef'] has been entered as 0.6
- $amount has been retrieved from XML as 2.50

$commision should be calculated as 1.50. However, it is printed as 1.20

I have found the reason of this difference when investigate from all other inputs that the fraction part of the $amount has not been taken for some reasons.

I could not figure out any possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Although the values coming from XML are seen as 2.50 with dot, I was suspicious that they may be as 2,50.

So I added the code `$amount        = str_replace(',', '.', $amount);` the problem is solved.